# how can I get a complete vector of residuals from an ARX model

Tags: matlab, statistics, time-series, signal-processing

I used [ARX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/ident/ref/arx.html) function then [RESID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/ident/ref/resid.html) function from the System Identification Toolbox, but the resulting residuals are:

```
0 
0
0
5
6
8
7
8
```

the number of zeros=the number of lags, I need a complete vector of residuals

Comment: This is not a coherent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [AR model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) of order N needs the previous N values to predict the next one, which is why the first N are not predicted. You can always pad the vector at the beginning (either by replication or zeros), example:

```
load twotankdata
order = 5;
m = arx(y, order);

r = resid([y(1:order);y], m);
r = r(order+1:end);
```